# I have converted a PDF to text, I am now attempting to remove unwanted text to then join back together to create a csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, text

I have collect election results from a state board of elections. They did not have the data available via csv so I have a PDF. I was able to convert the PDF to text using open with and them I split the lines because the spacing was off. My next step is to remove text that I do not want. I only want the ED#, the candidate and how many votes they received so I can convert to csv for calculation. FYI this PDF is 490 pages long.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: use pdfplumber python library. They have a table to dataframe conversion function. You can then save dataframe to csv